# Not able to do a pppos client initialisation for Cavli C10AM interfaced with ESP WROOM32

Tags: embedded-linux, iot, gsm, esp32, firmware

OS: Linux (Ubuntu Mate v20.04)
MCU: ESP WROOM 32
LTE Module: Cavli C10AM
Interface type: Typical UART interface
ESP-IDF Version: ESP-IDF v4.3-dev-2586-g526f68239

I am trying to interface ESP32 with Cavli C10AM LTE module and trying to upload files from ESP32 to server using LTE module. The connections are made (typical UART) and successfully initialised the LTE module using basic AT command. After initialisation, I am trying to initiate ppp connection from ESP32 to LTE module. I am using the inbuilt pppos_client library available in the ESP-IDF. But my DCE(LTE Module) is not been identified. I have also tried the same with SIM 800L GSM module, still no luck. The error screenshot is attached below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOPWC.png)

I have also tried the github code from the following repository.
Link: https://github.com/loboris/ESP32-PPPOS-EXAMPLE

For some reason I am not able to get the correct response for the ppp client connection. Without ppp connection I am not able to establish a secured SSL/TSL connection using mbedtls library.

Still no luck with it.

If anyone knows any solution to anyone of the above cases, please help me with it. Thanks in advance for any leads.

The google drive link of entire project is here: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1b6GLJlKufz7iCGBXcEjhz7qi6nf2eM5v

Since it has dependencies I have uploaded entire code.

components/libGSM.c contains the main library code.(containing the pppos function)

main->pppos_client_main.c is the main code, which is the entry point of the code.

The error related to pppos is:

```
    I (6361) [PPPOS CLIENT]: Skip command: [AT..]
    I (6361) [PPPOS CLIENT]: Skip command: [ATZ..]
    I (6361) [PPPOS CLIENT]: Skip command: [ATE0..]
I (6365) [PPPOS CLIENT]: Skip command: [AT+CFUN=1..]
I (6371) [PPPOS CLIENT]: Skip command: [AT+CNMI=0,0,0,0,0..]
I (6377) [PPPOS CLIENT]: Skip command: [AT+CPIN?..]
I (6482) [PPPOS CLIENT]: AT COMMAND: [AT+CREG?..]
I (6508) [PPPOS CLIENT]: AT RESPONSE: [..+CREG: 2,1,"2036","0ada5f17",7....OK..]
I (8608) [PPPOS CLIENT]: AT COMMAND: [AT+CGDATA="",1..]
I (8632) [PPPOS CLIENT]: AT RESPONSE: [..CONNECT..]
I (9632) [PPPOS CLIENT]: GSM initialized.
I (9664) [HTTPS]: Seeding the random number generator
I (9675) [HTTPS]: Loading the CA root certificate...
I (9682) [HTTPS]: Setting hostname for TLS session...
I (9685) [HTTPS]: Setting up the SSL/TLS structure...
I (9709) [HTTPS]: ===== HTTPS GET REQUEST =========================================

I (9709) [HTTPS]: Connecting to api.dozee.info:443...
E (9714) [HTTPS]: mbedtls_net_connect returned -52
I (9720) [HTTPS]: 0 bytes read, 0 in buffer
E (9724) [HTTPS]: Last error was: -0x52 - UNKNOWN ERROR CODE (0052)
I (9731) [HTTPS]: Waiting 300 sec...
I (9735) [HTTPS]: =================================================================
```

Comment: Firstly - please, please, please do not add any text output (such as error messages) as a screenshot. Copy and paste the text into your post, surrounded by relevant tags. Secondly, we can't help you without your code. Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Tarmo I have uploaded the code and provided the link and also provided error as a text along with the edited form of text. Please do check. Thank you.

Comment: Your drive link requires asking for additional permission - this is why you create a minimal sample project which demonstrates your problem and post it directly here. Anyway, the PPP connection seems to come up, the HTTPS connection attempt fails with -0x0052 which is ["Failed to get an IP address for the given hostname."](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/58fd20c464175cf502847d7e265f3252b48e8fb6/include/mbedtls/net_sockets.h#L60). I don't see any DNS servers being set up in the log - are you sure it's working?